# React Native JS: Hash history needs a DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am creating mobile app whit react native. I want to transerf web app on moblie. I have error:

```
 E/ReactNativeJS: Hash history needs a DOM
```

Comment: Here is tutorial on how to use latest react-router with react native https://medium.com/@jschloer/react-router-v4-with-react-native-5f2005ab2a72#.q5wmzwq71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use an in-memory history in order to use React Router with React Native.

In v2/3 you will have to create your `history` instances using [`createMemoryHistory`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/API.md#creatememoryhistoryoptions)

```
var history = createMemoryHistory()

const App = () => (
  <Router history={history} routes={...} />
)
```

v4 of React Router provides a [`<MemoryRouter>`](https://react-router.now.sh/MemoryRouter) component that will create an in-memory history for you.

```
const App = () => (
  <MemoryRouter>
    <View>...</View>
  </MemoryRouter>
)
```